# Suggested Settings for Mathematica over X11/SSH Tunnel

Tags: front-end, networking

I am happy to discover that I can run a Mathematica session tunneled over SSH.  However, as expected for X11 applications over the network, Mathematica's GUI does not have the responsiveness that I wish it had.

I have enabled SSH Compression to the highest level, and I am using ethernet connections where possible, though my cable modem is probably the bottleneck. For various reasons, I am unable to install NX, x2go, xpra, etc. Also, it turns out that remote MathKernel/local UI will not be an option.

It seems that some stock X applications (such as evince and gnome-terminal) run acceptably over my current setup.  My wish is to trim Mathematica GUI as much as possible, so as to minimize re-draws and the like which would slow things down.

I have been through the appearance preference pane, and turned off various "code intelligence" features which seem to cause things to redraw, and lowered graphics quality to their lowest. Also, I have disabled niceties such as the Suggestion Bar. But it is possible that I am missing something that others have found.

Which settings/modifications have you found to reduce the latency of Mathematica GUI sessions?

Comment: Why you don't use remote kernel? It is much-much faster then GUI forwarding.

Comment: 1) Policy prohibits storing data offsite 2) ssh is going through a tunnel via another machine, mathlink might be hard to set up 3) code written to read files/resources and paths are programmed around NoteBookDirectory[] 4) extra mathematica license 5) large/huge output of SQL Table dumps needs to stay on the server 6) ...

Comment: Can you provide some type of benchmark or other goal?  Leaving the question open ended with "what have you found" might be considered as too broad, although I for one am interested in answers.  As an aside: Not sure if there's a way around #4 or #5, but for #3, I believe NotebookDirectory[] will return the host directory - at least it does when I establish a remote kernel to a RPi from Windows.